# CSV data written to http response from data table is getting lost in C#

Tags: c#, csv, httpresponse, outputstream

I am writing some csv data into http response. This data is being fetched into a data table from database and then written into http response content using streamwriter. 
problem is that CSV file downloaded at client side does not contain all the data. It is always missing some of the data at the end of the file. Below is the code snippet:

```
System.Web.HttpResponse Response

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=Results.csv");
Response.AddHeader("content-type","text/plain");

writeCsvDataStream_ss(new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream), dt);
Response.End();

private void writeCsvDataStream_ss(StreamWriter Response, DataTable myDT)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    if (myDT.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        Response.Write("No Data available for selected ESIID");
        Response.Flush();
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <  myDT.Columns.Count; i++) 
    { result.Append(myDT.Columns[i].ColumnName); 
      result.Append(i == myDT.Columns.Count - 1 ? "\n" : ","); 
    }
    foreach (DataRow row in myDT.Rows) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i <  myDT.Columns.Count; i++) 
        { result.Append(row[i].ToString()); 
          result.Append(i == myDT.Columns.Count - 1 ? "\n" : ","); 
        } 
    }
    Response.Write(result.ToString());
}
```

I have tried many things but nothing worked. Could someone please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check http status.  You should be getting a 200 Done at end of the data.  You can sniff the data using Fiddler and verify that the 200 Done is occurring.  The common problem everybody has is WebRequest defaults to http 1.1 which doesn't work in Net Library.  You may need to change the request to http 1.0 using following : request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: What is your Response.Buffer set to? If false, you need to add a Response.Flush() before your call to Response.End().

Comment: If all data being written properly check that If you are directly opening in excel and if you have too much rows that excel can not handle(depending on version), try opening it in notepad or notepad++

Comment: tried adding Response.flush() before Response.end(), even tried Response.flush() in the loop after every 500 lines... also tried Notepad++ but no difference.

Comment: one more thing, i have made sure that **StringBuilder result** has all the data right before **Response.Write(result.ToString());**
So, now i am sure that problem is with **Response.Write(result.ToString());** ... somehow it is omitting some of the data at the end while writing into the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void writeCsvDataStream_ss(StreamWriter Response, DataTable dt)
{
   StringBuilder sbCsv ;
   for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
          sbCsv = new StringBuilder(1024);
          for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
          {
                sbCsv.Append(dt.Rows[i][j] + ";");
          }
          sbCsv.Append(Environment.NewLine);
          Response.Write(sbCsv.ToString());
          if (i % 1000) == 0)
              Response.Flush();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Alper. Tried this and it improved the result by adding a few more rows that were not showing up earlier... but still CSV is not carrying all the data it should. It's only a few more rows short at the end.

Comment: Also, i made sure that StringBuilder result has all the data right before Response.Write(result.ToString());
So, now i am sure that problem is with Response.Write(result.ToString()); ... somehow it is omitting some of the data at the end while writing into the response